# Attribute without @DatabaseField?

Tags: java, annotations, ormlite

Am I understanding well, if an attribute in data model is not annotated with `@DatabaseField` it will not persisted to DB?

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = "teacher_name")
public String teacherName;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> an attribute in data model is not annotated with @DatabaseField it will not persisted to DB?

ORMLite needs to know which fields from your entity you want to be persisted to the database.  It can do this a couple of different ways.  The "standard" way is to use the `@DatabaseField` annotation.  See [setting up your classes](http://ormlite.com/docs/class-setup).

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = "teacher_name")
public String teacherName;
```

You can also use the [Javax `@Column` annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/docs/jpa) as well.

```
@Column(name = "teacher_name")
public String teacherName;
```

The 3rd way you can configure your classes is through java code (or spring wiring).  See [class configuration documentation](http://ormlite.com/docs/class-config).

```
List<DatabaseFieldConfig> fieldConfigs = new ArrayList<>();
DatabaseFieldConfig field1 = new DatabaseFieldConfig("teacherName");
field1.setColumnName("teacher_name");
fieldConfigs.add(field1);
// add others if necessary ...
DatabaseTableConfig<Entity> tableConfig
    = new DatabaseTableConfig<Entity>(Entity.class, fieldConfigs);
```